# PSQLException: ERROR: column does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "nomenclature", schema = "public")
public class Nomenclature implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="nomenclature_versions",
            joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="nomenclature_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<NomenclatureVersion> version;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "nomenclature_versions", schema = "public")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NomenclatureVersion implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "nomenclature_id")
    private Long nomenclatureId;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    @Column(name = "puls_code")
    private String pulsCode;
    @Column(name = "pic_url")
    private String picUrl;
    @Column(name = "current")
    private boolean current;
}
```

When im trying to get Nomenclature with JPARepository getById(id) method im getting `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column version0_.version_id does not exist`

It feels like the problem is around Hibernate Naming Strategies but i cant solve it.

Is there any other way to let Hibernate know which column should it use to join tables?

Comment: JoinTable tells JPA to use a relational table to contain the mapping, much like a M:M situation. The actual cardinality can be controlled on a relational table using constraints on the foreign keys to the main entity tables, so a relational table can be used for any relation type, even 1:1s. It is just more common and usually efficient to have 1:1s use a FK directly in the entity, reducing some table joins and overhead. You have set it up trying to use the entity table as the relational table, which is a bad idea - It will work for reads, but not writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `@JoinTable`, the table is the same as the entity you are referencing. You just have to specify the `@JoinColumn`, hibernate will look for the column in the table referenced by the entity you are mapping the list to, `NomenclatureVersion` :

```java
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="nomenclature_id") 
private List<NomenclatureVersion> version;
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. But can you share some info or a link to read about what i was doing wrong?
I have another small project and @JoinTable worked there like a sharm in almost same conditions.

Comment: Of course. Vlad Migalcea is a Java Champion expert in JPA/hibernate. He has a blog with plenty of JPA related articles really interesting and inatructive. This is just one example https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Please, accept the answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks!